# Create a Wrapper based on an array of component in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to write a function to generate wrapper based on list of components.
In my app, I need to load services based on user login stage. And I want to make it a little bit configurable, using an array to store service components (provider).

current stage

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <DndService>
      <SubscriptionService> // activated only if user login
        <IMService> // activated only if user login
          <AppRender />
        </IMService>
      </SubscriptionService>
    </DndService>
  );
}
```

expected:

```js
const services = hasLogin ? [DndService, SubscriptionService, IMService] : [DndService];
const ServiceWrap = makeWrapper(services);
function App() {
  return (
     <ServiceWrap>
       <AppRender />
     </ServiceWrap>
  );
}
```

I think the `makeWrapper` should do something like `compose`, but I don't know how to make it right.

Answer (score 0):

I use `React.createElement` to handle component rendering.

```js
function makeWrapper(services) {
  return function(props) {
    return services.reduce(children, Service) {
      return React.createElement(Service, undefined, children);
    }, props.children);
  }
}
```